# How do I use Xfce widgets with Pygi?

Tags: python, gtk, gtkbuilder

I've been playing around with pygi recently, trying to put together a mixer plugin for xfce, but when I try to load the GtkBuilder file from python it doesn't recognize the XfceTitledDialog (which I'm trying to use for the configuration dialog).

Is there something special I need to do to use xfce widgets?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Aug 07 2010, 16:54:59) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk
>>> builder = Gtk.Builder()
>>> builder.add_from_file('xfvol.ui')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gi/types.py", line 40, in function
    return info.invoke(*args)
RuntimeError: Invalid object type `XfceTitledDialog'
```

Changing XfceTitledDialog to GtkDialog makes it work, but it's the wrong widget.
The widget is available and appears to work in Glade.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some shell environment variables that glade needs.

```
GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH=/usr/share/glade3/pixmaps
GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=:/usr/share/glade3/catalogs
GLADE_MODULE_PATH=:/usr/lib64/glade3/modules
LIBGLADE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/lib64/libglade/2.0
```

Make sure those are the right paths on your system and the the xfce modules are in there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've exported those variables (after confirming that they were correct) and then tried again, but I got the same error.